# How to map async key to call API

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-props

I have 2 classes, App.js and Categories.js. the App.js called an API and managed to get the name of the categories and the ID of the category into JSON, the data is then pushed like so and gets transfered into a prop of class Category

```
Object.keys(data.categories).forEach((category,index) => {
  categories.push(data.categories[index].name);
  categoryIDs.push(data.categories[index].id)
})


<Categories 
   categoryName = { this.state.categoryName }
   categoryID = { this.state.categoryID }
 />
```

Then in my Categories class, the data is returning a pair through a map button, and i used key to associate with the array values like a pair but I can't pass the values to help get the values needed to dynamically access the API

```
class Categories extends React.Component {


getResult= async () => {


    const api_call = await fetch(`
    http://callthisapi.com/v1/categories/items?format=json&category=1334134&apiKey=${API_KEY}`)

    // Convert response to json
    const data = await api_call.json();

    console.log(data);
}

render() {

    return (

    <div>
    <br /> 
        { 
            this.props.categoryName.map
                ((name,i) => <button key={i} onClick={this.getResult}> {name} {this.props.categoryID[i]} </button>)
        }
    </div>
```

as you can see the 1334134 is a hard coded value right now but the number is currently associated in `{this.props.categoryID[i]}`. How do i allow the number to change dynamically? I tried to pass in the value through a parameter but everything broke afterwards.

The value that I want is in `{this.props.categoryID[i]}` and I can't extract it to the function is the tl;dr

Comment: Passing the value as a parameter should work. How exactly did it break? Can you show what you tried and why it didn't work?

Comment: i'm not sure if i did it right but my parameter was `getResult= async (i)` then my call will be `http://callthisapi.com/v1/categories/items?format=json&category=${i}` if i'm on the right track then the props will be something like `<button key={i} onClick={this.getResult(this.props.categoryID[i])}>` i noticed that you can change the paramter to something like `${this.props.categoryID[i]` and just pass the i through there.

Comment: Your `getResult` looks good, just change your `onClick` to be `onClick={() => this.getResult(this.props.categoryID[i])}` and it should work. And you are correct that you can pass just the `i` if you prefer, and then adjust your parameter in the API call accordingly.

Comment: It works! thanks for showing me, I didn't know that i needed to do `() =>` first in order to pass the parameters properly, i was having issues to why it wasn't working when it was haha

Comment: You're welcome. The arrow function makes this.getResult() be called when the button is clicked. Without the arrow function, this.getResult() would be called immediately when the button renders. Check this out to see the difference ways to pass functions in props: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `onClick` to be `onClick={() => this.getResult(this.props.categoryID[i])}`.

Then getResult can accept a parameter: `getResult = async (id) => { ... }`

API call: `http://callthisapi.com/v1/categories/items?format=json&category=${id}`

See React documentation for passing functions: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html